# Is it off topic to promote the topic challenge here?

Tags: discussion

> Well, it's been a while.
>
> To our new(-er) users, welcome to Topic Challenges. To our old(-er) users, welcome back.
>
> In the spirit of improving the site, its questions and the amount of fun and learning (and teaching) that goes here, a tradition lost to time is now rekindled.
>
> I'm talking, of course, about Topic Challenges.
>
> The idea is to have a competition of sorts. Rather than have users compete, their questions compete. A better and more thorough description is in the linked post.
>
> The abridged version is:
>
> 1. A topic is chosen by the community, in Q&A style, right in this post. You can suggest a topic theme (see challenges #1 and #2 if you want a better idea of what's what) by posting your suggestion as an answer to this very question
> 2. Once a Topic is chosen, a meta post (like the previous two) will go up, and the challenge will begin 24 hours later (specific time will be stated in the post)
> 3. The challenges last one (1) week*. At the end of the week, a winner is announced by our all powerful amazing mod team.
> 4. You can find more details in here.
>
> And remember: There's no such thing as a wrong answer here! It's not CS Education if you're not allowed to make mistakes. So suggest to your hearts contest content!

I am referring to [this](https://cseducators.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/457/topic-challenges-iii-return-of-the-topic) at the CS Education site.

Comment: Please post real content instead of link chains. I fixed the link and copied over the post without markup; you may want to add the links and such.

Answer (score 4):

Announcements of any kind, as long as they are relevant to the cs.se community and not spam, are on-topic on meta.

If this is intended to be an announcement, you may want to make that more clear, though.

Comment: In the past, we've been hesitant to allow promotions of off-site material or events. There's just so much out there, we might open a can of worms. That said, a specific series of CS-related events on another SE sites may be worthwhile making an exception for.

Comment: @Raphael Yes, I vaguely recall reading that at some point. Is there are meta discussion about this? However, I think that these sort of things should be allowed, for a proper definition of relevant. What I think relevant should mean here is not only relevant for the people who use this site, but relevant to the Q&A function of this site, which would include promotion of events on other SE sites, but excludes things like promotion of arbitrary cs conferences.

Comment: I don't recall a general discussion, only case-specific decisions.

Comment: The problem is less about any specific promotion being appropriate but about where, when, and how to draw the line. It's way easier to define and execute a "no promotions" policy than a "select promotions allowed" policy.

Comment: This is indeed an announcement.